# Align H1 text in center with buttons vertically aligned right

Tags: html, css

I have a heading of `H1` center-aligned and I have two buttons on the right. As soon as I add the html for the buttons abve the `H1` element, the `H1` doesn't remain at the same height.

Here is a picture and my code:

[image: Buttons]

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html{font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color:#4A96AD;
color:#2a2a2a;
}
h1 {text-align:center;
font-size:70px;
font-weight:700;
color:#2a2a2a;
.btn {

  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  display: inline-block;
}
.green {
  color: #fff;
}
.green:hover { 
  color: #4A96AD;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}
.buttons {
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  float:top;
  margin:15px
}
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  display: inline-block;
}
.home {
  color: #4A96AD;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}
.button {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  margin:15px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Flash</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="btn home" href="abcd">Home</a>
    <a class="btn green" href="abcd">Next Page ></a>
</div>
<h1>FLASH</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, "FLASH" is below height of the buttons, All I want is to make the "FLASH" come at the same height as the buttons.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know there are duplicates all over the place for this fundamental question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html{font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color:#4A96AD;
color:#2a2a2a;
}
h1 {text-align:center;
font-size:70px;
font-weight:700;
color:#2a2a2a;}
.green {
  color: #fff;
}
.green:hover { 
  color: #4A96AD;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}
.buttons {
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  float:top;
  margin:15px
}
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  display: inline-block;
}
.home {
  color: #4A96AD;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Flash</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="btn home" href="abcd">Home</a>
    <a class="btn green" href="abcd">Next Page ></a>
</div>
<h1>FLASH</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .buttons div is a block level element, which is why it is pushing down your h1. All you need to do is float your .buttons div to the right.

Add this to your .buttons style:

```
  float: right;
```

Comment: It did work but now my h1 is no more centered. It has shifted a bit to the left when the buttons and h1 are at the same height. Thanks

Comment: @AyushTanna add   clear: both;  to your h1. That will fix it.